# SWIG error from unnecessary cast to const variable

Tags: c++, swig

In some test.i file, I have the following functions:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::string> test(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    std::return innerTest(arg1);
}

std::auto_ptr<std::string> innerTest(int arg)
{
    std::string("Non-const");
    std::auto_ptr<std::string> ret(&str);
    return ret;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: passing ‘const std::auto_ptr<std::basic_string<char> >’ as ‘this’
argument of ‘std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::operator std::auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>() 
[with _Tp1 = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers
```

In the generated test_wrap.cxx file, I find:

```
 resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new std::auto_ptr< std::string >
(static_cast< const std::auto_ptr< std::string >& >(result))), 
SWIGTYPE_p_std__auto_ptrT_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
```

Why is it trying to cast to a `const std::auto_ptr<std::string>` to construct the `std::auto_ptr<std::string>`, and how do I make it not do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3906019/27678

Comment: Is it acceptable for you if SWIG takes the ownership of the object from the auto ptr? That's simple to do and robust.